# Create Lists from List based on Matching Object Properties

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a list of objects which contain several properties. I am looking to break the list into several lists composed of objects which posses the same sub-property.

Here is a hypothetical example, say I have a list of `Cars`. Each `Car` has properties: `id`, `manufacturerId` and `color`.

I would like to create lists of `Cars` for those with matching `manufacturerId` properties.

I have tried using `list.where` within `list.forEach` to create new sub-lists, however I get duplicate lists because when the property I am comparing against (A) matches with another property (B), I get another sub-list when:

> B = A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`groupBy`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/groupBy.html) from `package:collection`

```
var carsByManufacturer = groupBy(cars, (car) => car.manufacturerId);
```

This will create a `Map` where the keys are the `manufacturerID`, and the values are lists of cars with that manufacturer.

Then do,

```
for (final manufacturerEntry in carsByManufacturer) {
      final key = manufacturerEntry.key;
      final value = manufacturerEntry.value;
      final listOfCarsFromSameManufactuer = List.from(entry.value);
      ...
}
```

You will now have lists called: `listOfCarsFromSameManufactuer`.